# Strange square brackets in recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence given:

$$a_{0}=1$$
$$a_{1}=1$$
$$a_{n}=3a_{n-2}+3a_{n-1}$$

Why is that equal to something like this?:

$$a_{n}=3a_{n-2}+3a_{n-1}-2[n=1]+[n=0 ]$$

What are those brackets?

Comment: If I recall correctly, these are also known as Iverson brackets, $[n=1]$ evaluates to $1$ if $n = 1$, and to $0$ if $n \neq 1$. Here, it could be simply done with the Kronecker delta, $a_n = 3a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-1} - 2\delta_{1n} + \delta_{0n}$

Comment: Argh. :)  You beat my answer, @DanielFischer. :)

Comment: @anorton I bet it was the link that held you up ;)

Comment: So...these Iverson brackets don't do anything here? Because for any n>1 Kronecker delta gives 0. If so, then is something like $a_{n}=3a_{n-2}+3a_{n-1}+[n=0]+[n=1 ]$ also equal to this recurrence?

Comment: To use Iverson brackets you'll need to assume that $a_n=0$ for $n<0$. This is no clearer than the original formulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are most likely [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).  If the Boolean expression inside the square bracket is true, then the bracket evaluates to $1$.  Otherwise, the bracket evaluates to $0$.